# Reversing an array of characters in python3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to reverse an array of characters:

```
def reverse(list_of_chars):
    reversed_string = []
    for x in range(len(list_of_chars)-1,0,-1):
        reversed_string.append(list_of_chars[x])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Reversing a string in place:

```
def reverse(list_of_chars):
    last_index = list_of_chars[len(list_of_chars) - 1]
    first_index = list_of_chars[0]

    while(first_index != last_index):
        first_index = list_of_chars[0]
        list_of_chars.remove(first_index)
        list_of_chars.append(first_index)

    pass
```

Comment: Why not just use `list(reversed(list_of_charaters))`?

Comment: Can't use the reversed method for my problem

Comment: Do I have to set 0 to -1? Since it will exclude 0?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong:

Ranges are exclusive of the last value, so your range will stop before it gets to `0`. You need the range to read:

```
range(len(list_of_chars) -1, -1, -1):
```

And you need to return the list.

```
def reverse(list_of_chars):
    reversed_string = []
    for x in range(len(list_of_chars) -1, -1, -1):
        reversed_string.append(list_of_chars[x])
    return reversed_string

print(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
# prints: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You can do this in a comprehension too, which might be easier to read:

```
def reverse(l):
    return [l[-(index + 1)] for index in range(len(l))]
```

Comment: Another question: If I want to reverse a string in place, here's my thought process:  
1. Declare last index 
2.Remove first index
3. Then append the first index to the array 
4. Repeat until the 1st index is equal to the last index (declared outside the while loop)

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: @koreannnnnnn you can reverse in place by swapping while iterating forward through half the range `l[x], l[-(x + 1)] =  l[-(x+1)],  l[x]`. This will swap first/last, then second/second to last...etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_chars = ['z','r','x','e','c']

def reverse(list_of_chars):
    reversed_string = []
    for x in range(len(list_of_chars)-1,-1,-1):
        reversed_string.append(list_of_chars[x])
    print(reversed_string)

reverse(list_of_chars)

output: ['c', 'e', 'x', 'r', 'z']
```